# How to set PDF title for base64 file while opening in new tab

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to open a base64 PDF file in a new tab by using iframe. While opening that PDF in new tab file name is showing as **data:** attached my screenshot below. How can I change or set the file name?.

**Note: I don't want to download the PDF I need to open in a new tab. Thanks in advance**

My Code

```
const pdfWindow = window.open('');
pdfWindow.document.write(
  "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " +
    encodeURI(base64PDF) +
    "'></iframe>",
);
```

[image]

Comment: do you mean the result of `<title>` tags in HTML pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to show the filename you want, but it needs to save the base64 to **LocalFileSystem**.

Then the iframe load this file in **LocalFileSystem**.

And it needs user to grant permission once to the browser.
[image]

It works on Chrome. You can refer to below demo:

https://pdf-filename.glitch.me/

Souce:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/pdf-filename?path=index.html%3A1%3A0

**The download button fail to work...**

**Edit:**

If you would like to use pdf.js, you can refer to:

https://daniel4wong-pdfjs-demo.glitch.me/

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Have you notice while opening the PDF in a new tab, download was not working.

Comment: Oh, so sad. Would you try to use the pdf.js viewer.html, this will then with different layout, but this would be a cross browser solution that most browser can have similar layout, you can see https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/es5/web/viewer.html

Comment: After downloaded the library in your web, you can use the library to pass base64 string (maybe buffer array or blob) to open the pdf in the iframe, and you can even control the DOM in the iframe to show / hide / add buttons you want

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this way you can use. There may have been a mistake in the arrangements.

```
let file = 'data:application/pdf;base64'
let prntWin = window.open();
prntWin.document.write("<html><head><title>your title in here</title></head><body>"
    + '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="'+ file + '" '
    + 'type="application/pdf" ></body></html>');
prntWin.document.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This will set the title. I need to change or set a file name. Check my screenshot at the top left corner

Comment: I had to show a tab title for PDF document opened in new tab and this worked well for me. I was just giving the iframe in document.write previously. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The title that you are refering to is in the metadata of the PDF document itself. You will need to edit the title in the document.

You can use an online editor (like https://pdfcandy.com/edit-pdf-meta.html) or any suitable PDF application.

If you are generating your PDF's on the backend you need to set the proper metadata over there.